# bind log Asynchronous in winForm c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I tried to add something to log inside WinForm while doind something

```
    private async Task SaveChunk(DataChunkSaver chunk)
    {
        int i = 0;
        int step = 10;

        while (chunk.saveChunk(i, step))
        {
            i += step;
            AddLog(chunk.Log);
        }
    }
```

where:

```
    private async Task AddLog(string text)
    {
        LogBulider.AppendLine(text);
         LogBox.Text = LogBulider.ToString();
    }
```

AndLogBulider is a simple global StringBulider.
The problem is when I fire button with SaveChunk task my form freezes, so I can see the LogBox after everything is done and I wanned it to bisplayed after each step of chunk.saveChunk.
I tried to fire them by few methods, but I can't handle it

What Am I doing wrong?

```
        private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => SaveChunk(chunk));
    Task T = SaveChunk(chunk);
    // none of these works, I also tried few other
//ways to do it, but none prevents my winForm from freezing
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Task.Run(()=>SaveChunk(chunk));` (without await!)? By the way you should not modify your GUI from a Non-GUI Thread. Have you considered a) using BackgroundWorker or b) IProgress ?

Comment: and make sure you use `await AddLog(chunk.Log)`; in you SaveChunk method. Using async methods without using await could create undesired behavior.

Comment: @RoelantM I think he should be doing the "logging" through an IProgress anyway. As is he is trying to modify the GUI from a ThreadPool-Thread.

Comment: Then I receive error because more than one task tries to get access totextBox named "LogBox"

Comment: I recommend you read this: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/reporting-progress-from-async-tasks.html

Comment: "Then I receive error because more than one task tries to get access" - That's what I said. You'd need to marshal that part to the GUI Thread. But that's not worth the hassle. Read above linked article and use an IProgress instead.

Comment: Thanks Fildor! I's sure your article will help.

Comment: @Fildor _Have you considered a) using BackgroundWorker_ - one of benefits of `async-await` is get rid of `BackgroundWorker` especially in IO operations.

Comment: @Fabio That's correct. Just wanted to know if he considered it. Or even knew about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to modify your code using a `Progress<string>`:

```
private async void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var progress = new Progress<string>(msg =>
    {
     LogBulider.AppendLine(msg);
     LogBox.Text = LogBulider.ToString();
    });
    await Task.Run(() => SaveChunk(chunk, progress));
}
```

and

```
private async Task SaveChunk(DataChunkSaver chunk, IProgress<string> progress)
{
    int i = 0;
    int step = 10;

    while (chunk.saveChunk(i, step))
    {
        i += step;
        progress?.Report(chunk.Log); // Always use progress as if it could be null!
    }
}
```

Comment: _Always use progress as if it could be null!_ - Why in case when private method `SaveChunk` is called in another private method `button2_Click` with properly instantiated instance of `Progress`?

Comment: @Fabio It's just a guideline. When you offer async APIs with convenience overloads ( one with only progress, one with only CancelationToken, one without neither of them ) it is recommended to relay to the full version ( with progress and token) using `null` for "without progress" and CancelationToken.NONE for "without cancellation". So you will have to always treat progress as if it could be null. In this special case, you could also ignore that, but it doesn't hurt, does it?

Comment: And you could still later on use the private function elsewhere, where you don't want a progress. Yeah, maybe it's just me, but I always have the thought of "that's optional" when using progress.

Comment: Sorry, never used `IProgress` by myself, that is the reason of the question. I found `.?` operator provides some kind of "trap"  - I prefer to make sure that  `null` reference will not be passed around and get rid of possible null checking

Comment: @Fabio exactly `progress?.Report()` is about equvalent to `if( progress != null ) progress.Report();` Of course you also could make a "Silent Progress" as a NullObject-Pattern. I am not arguing against that.

Comment: @Fabio FYI , I found the source where I read that ... "If TAP implementations provide overloads that accept a progress parameter, **they must allow the argument to be null**, in which case no progress will be reported." Cited from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap